# Looking for ways to edit Xamarin code on the run

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

This question could be split in 2:

- is there any way to update xaml form markup in runtime and see the changes after re-entering the form? Similar to the way we can update asp.net pages in runtime
- is there any way to update xaml.cs class in runtime? If I try, it shows me deceptive message

[image]

which is not true, as the change is small and compilable
Another strange thing displayed after that is the error in the Error List window
[image]
However project is already build on .net standard 2.1.0.0, and can see it in the project properties

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### XAML

Using [XAML Hot Reload](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-bramin), it is possible to update your XAML during runtime and see the updates in real-time on the device/simulator.

[image]

#### C#

It is not currently possible to update and see your C# code changes during runtime.

The Xamarin engineering team is working on adding this feature and ou can follow their progress here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/650684/c-hot-reload-xamarin.html